# asp.NET 4.8 Informing loading during the initial Page loading

Tags: asp.net, loading

I have an old ASP.NET (.NET 4.8) Web application. One particular page requires lots of the database queries to get the result set during the initial load (i.e. inside!Page.IsPostBack), and it normally takes about 5 minutes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //divLoading.Visible = true; // This approach doesn't work.
        // Queries take about 5 min.
        //divLoading.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I have a custome Loading.Show() & Loading.Hide() javascript functions, and tried to Show it at loading time in ASPX as below, but it doesn’t display the loading icon.

```
<div id="divLoading" runat="server" Style="width: 300px; height: 320px; visibility:hidden">
  <asp:Label ID="lblLoading"  runat="server" Text="Please wait..." />
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnLoad() {
        Loading.Show();
    }
    window.onload = OnLoad;
    ...
</script>
```

How can I make it work?
Any alternative or advice PLEASE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to let/have the page fully render on the client side, and THEN have the client-side code click a button.

So, move your !IsPostBack code stub from page load event to behind a standard button event stub. Then it is a simple matter to let the web page render, have the client-side page "on load" event display the spinner or "please wait area", and then that same client code can click our button using client-side JavaScript.

Of course, we only want that code to run on first page load, so we introduce a client side myIsPostBack variable.

So, for an example, we will do a "fake" long loading process.

So, this markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdMyProcess" runat="server" Text="Proccess data"
            OnClick="cmdMyProcess_Click"
            Style="display: none"
            ClientIDMode="Static" />

        <div id="myprocesswait" style="display: none">
            <h3>Loading data - please wait</h3>
            <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" width="48" />
        </div>

        <script>

            function IsPostBack() {
                return '<%= Page.IsPostBack.ToString() %>'
            }

            $(window).on('load', function () {

                if (IsPostBack() == 'False') {
                    $('#myprocesswait').show()
                    $('#cmdMyProcess').click()
                }

            });

        </script>
```

So, note how the button (and div) have display = none.

And we created a client side IsPostBack function.

So, the effect when the page load is this:

[image]

However, such code will only run on the real first page load, just like the !IsPostBack flag is used in code behind, with above, you can use the client side IsPostBack function for the same purpose. Such code will only thus run on the first page load.

It is now a simple matter to move your page load !IsPostBack code stub to the above hidden button and use client side code to "click" that button, and only do so on the first real page load (IsPostBack = false).

Comment: Thank you again for this brilliant suggestion. It works like charm!

Comment: @AlbertDKallal I have a quick question. I forgot to write `$('#myprocesswait').hide()` in `cmdMyProcess_Click()` event. However, once that event finishes, the spinner gets hidden. Can you explain how this is possible?

Comment: By default the spinner div area is hidden.  So we show it and then click our hidden button.  Page life cycle starts and page is posted to server.  Only after button code is 100% done does the browser page return back to client.  When browser page returns then a whole new fresh copy of the browser page is re loaded.  That fresh new whole page doesn't have the div showing- it returns to hidden state. That div doesn't have a viewstate or run at server tag. So it will on any button click or any post back thus return to hidden.  We don't have to hide it unless no post back doesn't occur